# How to detect the number of fingers used on windows 8

Tags: windows-8, multi-touch

I simply want to know the number of contact points on the screen when doing a windows 8 app.
My scneario is that I want to rate an article simply by holding 1-5 fingers in a designated area for X seconds, but I'm having trouble detecting the number of contact points.

Any ideas?

Comment: this isn't a helpful response... but would consider usability of such a gesture. It's rather awkward to get all five fingers on a screen versus moving a slider or tapping one of a discrete number of options.  And if 5 is required for some value of the input (# of fingers == rating?), it limits accessibility as well.

Comment: I will not argue that, it's just a prototype kind of thing, and we're playing with concepts, and wondering how this could be done :)

Answer (score 1):

You will get a `WM_POINTERDOWN` message for each contact made, and a corresponding `WM_POINTERUP` when the contact is released. (Or you will get a `WM_POINTERCAPTURECHANGED` when you lose all contacts.) You can manually track how many are down, or you can ask `GetPointerFrameInfo` for the status of all contacts in the current frame.

Comment: How does that translate to c#?